# Dojo toolkit: How to invoke $(document).someFunction() equivalent

Tags: jquery, html, dojo

I can't seem to figure out how to call a function from a .js file in my html page.
The jquery equivalent is in the title:

```
$(document).someFunction();
```

But how do I do this in dojo?
I seems like its really simple, but I can't figure it out :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo takes the approach of giving you functions you pass elements into, rather than giving you a wrapper object you call functions on the way jQuery does.

So for instance:

```
require(['dojo/dom', 'dojo/domClass'], function(dom, domClass) {
    var elm = dom.byId("someElement");
    domClass.add(elm, "class-to-add");
});
```

More in [the 'Hello Dojo!' tutorial on the Dojo site](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/hello_dojo/).

Comment: I understand that with html tags I have created. But how specifically would this translate to $(document) ?

Comment: @MarcHPunkt: `document` is the node you would pass into Dojo methods. What exactly is you want to **do** to `document`?

Comment: Basically I was testing foundation front-end framework with dojo.
Now, this framework has a dependency on jquery and asks me to init it with the call $(document).foundation().  

Since the function is appended via $.fn, is it even possible to call the init via dojo? I'm sorry I didn't put it in the main. I though it was trivial and I was being stupid

Comment: @MarcHPunkt: If the framework has a dependency on jQuery, then why wouldn't you just use `$(document).someFunction();`? You'll need jQuery loaded anyway. If there's some conflict on the `$` symbol, you can use `jQuery(document).someFunction();` instead.

Comment: I know I know... I just wanted to practice dojo (and be cool)

Comment: @MarcHPunkt: Well, the answer is: You can't (reasonably) trigger a jQuery plugin via Dojo.